# Mean of columns while ignoring variable number of elements

Tags: r

How do get column wise mean while selecting variable number of elements from each column?

example:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,0,0)
b<-c(1,2,3,4,0)
c<-c(1,2,3,4,5)

d<- cbind(a,b,c)
```

How do I get mean of each column while ignoring variable number of elements from below (count of zeros in above example)? colMeans would return (1+2+3+0+0)/5 = 1.2 for mean of a, I want to get (1+2+3)/3 =2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution here.

```
>apply(d, 2, function(x) mean(subset(x, !x==0)))

  a   b   c 
2.0 2.5 3.0
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also avoid `apply` loops by assigning `NA` to zeros

```
d[d == 0] <- NA
colMeans(d, na.rm = TRUE)
##   a   b   c 
## 2.0 2.5 3.0
```

Or if you don't want to replace zeros with `NA`, the fastest way to solve this will be using `data.table` package (assuming `d` is your original untransformed data)

```
library(data.table)
as.data.table(d)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x[x != 0]))]
##    a   b c
## 1: 2 2.5 3
```

Answer (score 1):

For this specific task you could, also, use:

```
tmp = d != 0
colSums(d * tmp) / colSums(tmp)
  a   b   c 
2.0 2.5 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to write a function that replaces all 0's with NAs first, and then to compute the mean. For instance,

```
 my.mean <- function(x, num){
            new.x <- ifelse(x==num, NA, x)
            return(mean(new.x, na.rm=T))
 }
```

Then,

```
 my.mean(a, 0)
```

yields

```
 2
```

Note that you can easily adjust this function to make it more convenient. For instance, if you will never need to ignore any other value than 0, you can hardcode the 0 into the function and drop the second argument alltogether.

Moreover, if you want to apply the function to several columns, you can use the standard `R` ways for doing this. For instance, try

```
 apply(d, 2, my.mean, num=0)
```

which returns

```
   a   b   c 
  2.0 2.5 3.0
```